# Sum of 32 bits after inverting bits, final result going from binary to decimal

Tags: java, for-loop, int

If my input is 1. Then 1 as 32 bits in binary is 00000000000000000000000000000001. If I invert the bits, its 11111111111111111111111111111110. And if I convert this inverted bit number from binary to decimal, I should get 4294967294. I wrote the following program to do this, but my final sum is wrong despite me being able to invert the bits correctly. I'm getting -3.

Here is my code:

```
public class FlippingBits {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FlippingBits fpb = new FlippingBits();
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;
    int[] bitArray = new int[32];
    fpb.convertToBin(i, bitArray, index);
}

private void convertToBin(int decimalInput, int[] unsigned32, int index) {
    if (decimalInput <= 1) {
        unsigned32[index++] = flipBit(decimalInput);
        for (int i = index; i < unsigned32.length; i++) {
            unsigned32[i] = 1;
        }
        printArray(unsigned32);
        System.out.println();
        sumBit(unsigned32);
        return;
    }
    int remainder = decimalInput % 2;
    unsigned32[index] = flipBit(remainder);
    index++;
    convertToBin(decimalInput >> 1, unsigned32, index);
}

private void sumBit(int[] unsigned32) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < unsigned32.length; i++) {
        sum += unsigned32[i] * (int) Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

private int flipBit(int remainder) {
    if (remainder == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

private void printArray(int[] unsigned32) {
    for (int i = 0; i < unsigned32.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(unsigned32[i]);
    }
}

}
```

I'm not sure what's happening with my sumBit(int[]) method. I'm pretty sure I haven't forgotten how to convert from binary to decimal.

Comment: You need to read up on [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually using unsigned ints. You are overflowing your variable.

Comment: I'm not trying to use unsigned ints. How can fix the overflow problem?

Comment: if you use signed ints you have an overflow.  there is no workaround.

Comment: When you are summing use a long instead of an int.

Comment: Isn't there a bitwise XOR operator for this?

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
public class FlippingBits {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FlippingBits fpb = new FlippingBits();
    int i = 1;
    int index = 0;
    int[] bitArray = new int[32];
    fpb.convertToBin(i, bitArray, index);
}

private void convertToBin(int decimalInput, int[] unsigned32, int index) {
    if (decimalInput <= 1) {
        unsigned32[index++] = flipBit(decimalInput);
        for (int i = index; i < unsigned32.length; i++) {
            unsigned32[i] = 1;
        }
        printArray(unsigned32);
        System.out.println();
        sumBit(unsigned32);
        return;
    }
    int remainder = decimalInput % 2;
    unsigned32[index] = flipBit(remainder);
    index++;
    convertToBin(decimalInput >> 1, unsigned32, index);
}

private void sumBit(int[] unsigned32) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = unsigned32.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += unsigned32[i] * (int) Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}

private int flipBit(int remainder) {
    if (remainder == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

private void printArray(int[] unsigned32) {
    for (int i = unsigned32.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(unsigned32[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement, see http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~cs151/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch03s09.html for more info